# Can indicator actions be accessed via the HUD in 13.10?

Tags: unity, indicator, 13.10, hud

In 13.04 and before, it was possible to access the indicator’s menus via the HUD. E.g., in order to establish a VPN connection through network manager, it was sufficient to open the HUD and type "VPN". Or to shutdown the computer, one could open the HUD and type "shutdown".

In 13.10, it looks like the HUD only searches the currently active application. Is there a way to access indicators through the HUD in 13.10?

Comment: I noticed that too. It seems it was removed due to a design decision (https://bugs.launchpad.net/hud/+bug/1165420).

Comment: Apparently is also a bug. Bug controllers aren't sure

Comment: Alternatives include gnome-do (which allowed at least some of the stuff you do through the old HUD) and Alt-F10 followed by the Left arrow to get to the indicator menus.